# При обновлении данных в mysql вставляются вопросы hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, кодировка

SQL

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

Метод для обновления данных

```
    public int updateUserData(UserDataEntity entity) {
    var session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    int result = session.createQuery("update UserDataEntity ude set ude.firstName=:fname, ude.lastName=:lname, ude.patronymic=:patronymic, ude.birthday=:birthday, ude.phone=:phone, ude.otherData=:otherData, ude.status=:status where ude.userId=:userId")
            .setParameter("fname", entity.getFirstName())
            .setParameter("lname", entity.getLastName())
            .setParameter("patronymic", entity.getPatronymic())
            .setParameter("birthday", entity.getBirthday())
            .setParameter("phone", entity.getPhone())
            .setParameter("otherData", entity.getOtherData())
            .setParameter("status", entity.getStatus())
            .setParameter("userId",entity.getUserId())
            .executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите исправить.

Comment: `SET NAMES UTF8`?

Comment: @Akina немного не понял вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте кодировку базы данных на `UTF-8`